# How to configure max line count/data size of console output in run/debug window

Tags: intellij-idea

Sometimes I need to produce somewhat longer log to find usefull information. I understand, that long logs are harder to work with in graphical apps, and that I can log to console and to file and it would be better for processing, but just to know if this is possible/how:  What is the line/data limit to show up in run/debug configuration console and how can I re-set these values? I'd like to max this out, but it seemingly cannot be find anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open the Preferences
2. Navigate to Editor > General > Console
3. Check the Override console cycle buffer size (1024 KB)

Set to higher values for longer logs.